# GA -- Javascript Array Auto's onClick with Name in Alpha

Tags: javascript, css, google-analytics

I'm trying to come up with a Script; using perhaps, '`Math` Method in Javascript -- that allows me to simply attach a CSS class to dozens of files / photos / media, etc that I am using google Analytics to track `onClick`.

Essentially; I've been implementing the below, manually; across dozens of sites where I want to track `onClick`.

```
<p class="downloadsmall">download: <a href="jpg/LOW/1.jpg" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/img/LowRes/1.jpg']);">Low Res</a></p>
```

I'm wondering if I can simply define a class here; and within a JavaScript array or similar; I call the class attached to the mark-up; that assigns Google's `onClick` Tracking code automatically; while at the same time populating the name differently, in a simple way; like adding a 1,2,3 etc at the end of the name.

EG;

```
'/downloads/img/LowRes01.jpg']);">Low Res</a></p>
'/downloads/img/LowRes02.jpg']);">Low Res</a></p>
```

****Anyone have any suggestions as to how I can write this?*** Is it possible?*

---

**Update: //** 
Below is the full code I'm trying; The standard GA seems to read, but it is not resolving any of the `onClicks`? I've checked under 'Content Drilldown' and 'Events' and nothing is seeming to resolve except the Basic 'GA' Reading.

```
<!doctype html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35609953-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

<!-- GA track all onClicks -->

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.downloadsmall a').attr("onclick", function(i){
        var x='LowRes0'+(i+1)+'.jpg';
        return "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/img/"+x+"'])";
    });
});​
</script>

<!-- End GA track all onClicks -->

<style>

#wrap {
    width: 940px;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
}

#left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.downloadsmall {
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
border: 3px dotted #333;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrap"><!-- Wrap -->

    <div id="left">

<p class="downloadsmall">
    download: <a href="http://www.google.com">Low Res</a>
</p>

    </div>

  <div id="right">

<p class="downloadsmall">
    download: <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Low Res</a>
</p>

    </div>
    </div><!-- Wrap -->


</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE --** 
// I now have it so it is reading the page 'events' and is tracking the page views, but it is not categorizing as LowRes01.jpg - LowRes02.jpg according to the attached class; which was the main goal -- Below is my updated Full Code. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
<!doctype html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35609953-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', '/downloads/img/LowRes01.jpg']);


  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

<!-- GA track all onClicks -->

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.downloadsmall a').attr("onclick", function(i){
        var x='LowRes0'+(i+1)+'.jpg';
        return "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/img/"+x+"'])";
        return "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', '/downloads/img/"+x+"'])";

    });
});​
</script>

<!-- End GA track all onClicks -->

<style>

#wrap {
    width: 940px;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
}

#left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.downloadsmall {
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
border: 3px dotted #333;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrap"><!-- Wrap -->

    <div id="left">

<p class="downloadsmall">
    download: <a href="http://www.google.com">Low Res</a>
</p>

    </div>

  <div id="right">

<p class="downloadsmall">
    download: <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Low Res</a>
</p>

    </div>
    </div><!-- Wrap -->


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean something like this

```
$(function(){
    $('.downloadsmall a').attr("onclick", function(i){
        var x='LowRes0'+(i+1)+'.jpg';
        return "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/img/"+x+"'])";
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dmG7T/) (See the html source).

### Source

```
<p class="downloadsmall"> download: <a href="jpg/LOW/1.jpg">Low Res</a></p>
<p class="downloadsmall"> download: <a href="jpg/LOW/2.jpg">Low Res</a></p>
```

### Outout

```
<p class="downloadsmall">
    download: <a href="jpg/LOW/1.jpg" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/img/LowRes01.jpg'])">Low Res</a>
</p>
<p class="downloadsmall">
    download: <a href="jpg/LOW/2.jpg" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/img/LowRes02.jpg'])">Low Res</a>
</p>
```

### Update:

To track the event you have to use event tracking method of `GA`, i.e

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', '/downloads/img/LowRes01.jpg']);
```

and that's displayed as `Events` in the Analytics reporting interface. So, I think it should be like

```
$(function(){
    $('.downloadsmall a').attr("onclick", function(i){
        var x='LowRes0'+(i+1)+'.jpg';
        return "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', '/downloads/img/"+x+"'])";
    });
});​
```

For more [**read this**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).

Comment: Thanks, this looks awesome! Doing a test on it now.

Comment: Thanks -- But so far the general GA has resolved and I am seeing basic tracking; but I am not seeing the onClicks -- would they be stored in the same place; or ... ?

Comment: I've updated the Q - can let me know if I did anything wrong? Excited to see this resolve !!

Comment: Hey Sheikh - thanks for your Rad responses, however I still cannot get it ? I've just pasted the full code I've tried above; do you mind taking a peak. Am I not able to 'return normal page view' with 'event page view' within same area ?!

Comment: I've updated it again and to track event you have to use `_trackEvent` method, it's not possible using `_trackPageview`, remove the first `return` statement from your code, it's just terminating the execution at that line so it's not working.